# A simpler proof of Morley's Congruence?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Morley's Congruence states that for all primes $p \geq 5$, the following equivalence holds:
$$(-1)^\frac{p-1}{2} \binom{p-1}{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 4^{p-1} \mod{p^3}$$
I've seen a proof for this using only elementary number theory methods [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3678.pdf), but... it doesn't make sense to me at all? Can someone walk me through and explain how this was derived in the first place? (note: I'm a high school student who's interested in math olympiads, but I'm not particularly good at them.. yet. I don't remember how I found this theorem, but it seems really interesting to me!)